# CSS - Select text elements

Tags: css

I want to select everything after the div with class="good" and make them disappear.

```
<div class="amazing">
    <div class="good"></div>
    "bad text"
    <a class="bad"></a>
    "worse text"
    <a class="worse"></a>
</div>
```

I tried this but it didn't get rid of the texts.

```
.amazing a:nth-last-child(n+4) {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: That's an invalid HTML structure. Try closing the `<a>` with `</a>` first. And close the last `div` `</div>` too.

Comment: Your <a> has nothing in them so kinda pointless atm

Comment: CSS can't select text nodes

Comment: @Dylan Kas this is just an example.

Comment: @NoobCoder Posting "just an example" doesn't help. We need the real code, or at least, something resembling the real code, before we even can think about a solution. With your current example, the solution to the question asked is to hide everything in the container div. `.amazing {height:0; overflow:hidden;}`

Comment: @MrLister This actually worked! Thank you. Can you explain the code though, how it works.

Comment: `height:0` sets the height to 0 and `overflow:hidden` hides the overflow. This works because there is nothing in the container before the `good` div, so there is nothing that needs to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="amazing">
    <div class="good">This is good</div>
    <a class="bad">bad text</a>
    <a class="worse">worse text</a>
</div>
```

and

```
.amazing a {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it well, you wish to hide all texts after the `div` of `.good`

```css
/*Select All But The First One*/
.amazing div:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="amazing">
  <div class="good">"good text"</div>
  <div class="bad">"bad text"</div>
  <div class="worse">"worse text"</div>
</div>
```